# Running a new task with terraform without a service in ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to run a task with ecs without a service via terraform. But when i do the following, the **service** is required to set in terraform. How is it possible to set a task without a services?

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_set" "example" {
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.foo.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.fromecr.arn

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is not really possible without a local provisioner. There is an feature request for the Terraform AWS provider on github: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1703 it is still open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) to run AWS CLI to call [run-task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html).

Answer (score 2):

If the task definition is already present, then you can run the task using a null resource with a local exec provisioner. (Necessary permissions are to be given though. Below is a code snippet that explains this.

```
resource aws_ecs_task_definition "task_definition" {
      ....
      ....
     // your task definition code.
      ....
      ....
}

resource "null_resource" "migration_task_run" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition    // to make sure that you run task only after creating the task definition
  ]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
    aws ecs run-task \
      --cluster <<cluster_name>> \
      --task-definition <<task_definition_name>> \
      --count 1 --launch-type FARGATE \
      --network-configuration '{     // This is required if you have chosen awsvpc in network config for your task definition. Else, this can be ignored
      "awsvpcConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp":"DISABLED",
      "securityGroups": ["<<security_group>>"],
      "subnets": ["<<your subnets>>"]
      }
      }'
EOF
  }
}
```