# Aws ECS task using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I am deploying an application using ECS in AWS through terraform.
I am stuck
I want to create 1 task that should stop after its completion and 1 service that will continue to run.

When I do everything manually through AWS console, then I get an option to create a task (which will stop after its completion) and a service as well.

But when I try to perform the same using terraform, then I have a roadblock. I can't find any resource that will create a task instead of service. If there is any lifecycle block or any other block within the service that I have missed to add then let me know about that as well.

I want the dbmigrator task to stop after its completion and I want the apihost service to continue to run

Please guide me!

```
# CREATING ECS CLUSTER
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs_cluster" {
  name = "${var.project_name}-cluster"
}


# CREATING ECS SERVICE FOR DB MIGRATOR
resource "aws_ecs_service" "dbmigrator_service" {
  name            = "DBMigratorService"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.td_dbmigrator.arn
  desired_count   = 1 # Desired tasks
  depends_on      = [aws_db_instance.rds_cluster]
}


# CREATING SERVICE FOR APIHOST
resource "aws_ecs_service" "apihost_service" {
  name            = "ApiHostService"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.td_apihost.arn
  desired_count   = 1 # Desired tasks: 1

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.tg_apihost.arn
    container_name   = "apihost"
    container_port   = 80
  }

  # Ensuring that the web_service depends on the db_migrator_service
  depends_on = [aws_ecs_service.dbmigrator_service]
}
```

Many people have suggested me to use local-exec provisioner (like below)
But I think that won't work because my terraform code will be executed from terraform cloud and local-exec will not work over there.
Is there any other way??
If anyone is giving a solution, please give it according to my use case, I will be executing this terraform script through TERRAFORM CLOUD, and I have used bridge network mode in task definition , NOT awsvpc.
Please help!

```
resource aws_ecs_task_definition "task_definition" {
  
  // your task definition code.
  
  
}

resource "null_resource" "migration_task_run" {
  depends_on = [aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition    // to make 
  sure that you run task only after creating the task definition
]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = <<EOF
   aws ecs run-task \
   --cluster <<cluster_name>> \
   --task-definition <<task_definition_name>> \
   --count 1 --launch-type FARGATE \
   --network-configuration '{     // This is required if you have chosen 
   awsvpc in network config for your task definition. Else, this can be 
   ignored
   "awsvpcConfiguration": {
   "assignPublicIp":"DISABLED",
   "securityGroups": ["<<security_group>>"],
   "subnets": ["<<your subnets>>"]
   }
   }'
EOF
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a new task with terraform without a service in ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72506241/running-a-new-task-with-terraform-without-a-service-in-ecs)

Comment: Terraform doesn't have a resource for one-off ECS tasks. Terraform only really works for defining resources that are going to continue to exist for a long time, and still be there the next time you run a terraform plan/apply. For a single one-off ECS task you need to use a different tool like the AWS CLI to actually run the task. Or create a scheduled ECS task in Terraform who's schedule only runs once.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is not solvable with Terraform. Terraform will manage infrastructure that is permanent and every execution should be idempotent. In your case, the migration task is not.

Why? because you are trying to use an infrastructure-as-code tool to deploy a new container. That responsibility is part of a CI/CD pipeline that needs to wait until every single step is executed correctly, and needs to ensure the smooth transition from your current deployment to the next.

There are limitations on the APIs that Terraform executes. AWS hides part of the complexity under the rug when working with ECS and the `aws_ecs_service` resource continues in that line. If the Terraform executions where completely idempotent, the version number of a task definition should always be the same.

On the other side, it's possible to describe with Terraform an AWS CodeBuild pipeline, or a Github workflow. So it's possible to build the CI/CD pipeline, but Terraform cannot be used to execute it.